# Weird Applescript behavior - different result from script app

Tags: applescript, editor

Just try this :

```
set x to paragraphs of (do shell script "ls /Volumes")
set x to (choose from list x)
tell application "Finder" -- it can be system events also
    set f to ((the format of disk named x) as text)
    display dialog f
end tell
```

You get flawless result when in Script Editor, but when you save it as a script app, you get jibberish like "«constant ****dfh+»"

It just doesn't matter how you change the course of getting the disk format data, the result is always perfectly fine with the Script Editor, but totally mangled with script app

Do you guys have any idea what is going on here? Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The Script Editor will expand those constants to their name by using the application's scripting dictionary,  but _your_ application doesn't do that, so unless it does its own substitution just the raw code will be shown.

Comment: After a decade of extensive scripting on Mac, I've never heard anything like that, I never knew that - thanks, you are a guru

Answer (score 0):

the definitions are stored in the "finder.sdef" file

here is the table :

```
        <enumeration name="edfm" code="edfm">
        <enumerator name="Mac OS format" code="dfhf"/>
        <enumerator name="Mac OS Extended format" code="dfh+"/>
        <enumerator name="UFS format" code="dfuf"/>
        <enumerator name="NFS format" code="dfnf"/>
        <enumerator name="audio format" code="dfau"/>
        <enumerator name="ProDOS format" code="dfpr"/>
        <enumerator name="MSDOS format" code="dfms"/>
        <enumerator name="NTFS format" code="dfnt"/>
        <enumerator name="ISO 9660 format" code="df96"/>
        <enumerator name="High Sierra format" code="dfhs"/>
        <enumerator name="QuickTake format" code="dfqt"/>
        <enumerator name="Apple Photo format" code="dfph"/>
        <enumerator name="AppleShare format" code="dfas"/>
        <enumerator name="UDF format" code="dfud"/>
        <enumerator name="WebDAV format" code="dfwd"/>
        <enumerator name="FTP format" code="dfft"/>
        <enumerator name="Packet written UDF format" code="dfpu"/>
        <enumerator name="Xsan format" code="dfac"/>
        <enumerator name="APFS format" code="dfap"/>
        <enumerator name="ExFAT format" code="dfxf"/>
        <enumerator name="SMB format" code="dfsm"/>
        <enumerator name="unknown format" code="df??"/>
    </enumeration>
```

And here is a table for Applescript

```
set convertTable to {{"edfm", "edfm"}, {"Mac OS format", "dfhf"}, {"Mac OS Extended format", "dfh+"}, {"UFS format", "dfuf"}, {"NFS format", "dfnf"}, {"audio format", "dfau"}, {"ProDOS format", "dfpr"}, {"MSDOS format", "dfms"}, {"NTFS format", "dfnt"}, {"ISO 9660 format", "df96"}, {"High Sierra format", "dfhs"}, {"QuickTake format", "dfqt"}, {"Apple Photo format", "dfph"}, {"AppleShare format", "dfas"}, {"UDF format", "dfud"}, {"WebDAV format", "dfwd"}, {"FTP format", "dfft"}, {"Packet written UDF format", "dfpu"}, {"Xsan format", "dfac"}, {"APFS format", "dfap"}, {"ExFAT format", "dfxf"}, {"SMB format", "dfsm"}, {"unknown format", "df??"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Scripts use a lot of event codes for classes, constants, properties, etc.  If you are using [Script Debugger](https://latenightsw.com) and set it to show the raw syntax, you will see that they are everywhere.  *Script editors* will normally expand those items to their matching name, description, or whatever by using the various scripting dictionaries that it loads for editing the script.  *Your* application doesn't do any of that, so it just gets the raw codes.

One solution would be to have a bunch of `if` statements to set a string depending on the constant, another would be to set up a dictionary with key/value pairs for the desired enumerator constants and their names.  For the latter some AppleScriptObjC can be used to set up a NSDictionary, since regular AppleScript doesn't have the ability to look up record keys dynamically (although some gymnastics via `run script` can be used).

Using your posted script as a template, the following example creates a record/dictionary using values from the Finder's scripting dictionary (note that System Events has fewer items), with an additional check to see if the format is a constant (from running as an app).

```
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

set edfmEnum to current application's NSDictionary's dictionaryWithDictionary:{|df??|:"unknown format", dfxf:"ExFAT format", dfhf:"Mac OS format", dfsm:"SMB format", dfnt:"NTFS format", dfms:"MSDOS format", dfap:"APFS format", dfuf:"UFS format", dfph:"Apple Photo format", dfau:"audio format", dfnf:"NFS format", dfhs:"High Sierra format", dfud:"UDF format", dfpr:"ProDOS format", dfas:"AppleShare format", |dfh+|:"Mac OS Extended format", dfwd:"WebDAV format", dfft:"FTP format", dfpu:"Packet written UDF format", df96:"ISO 9660 format", dfac:"Xsan format", dfqt:"QuickTake format"} -- edfm enumeration items from Finder.sdef

set choice to (choose from list (paragraphs of (do shell script "ls /Volumes")))
if choice is not false then
   tell application "Finder" to tell disk named choice to set {theName, theFormat} to {name as text, format as text}
   if theFormat starts with "«constant" then -- look up the enum
      set theFormat to (edfmEnum's objectForKey:(last word of theFormat))
      if theFormat is missing value then set theFormat to "format not found"
   end if
   activate me
   display dialog (theFormat as text) with title ("Format of Disk '" & theName & "'")
end if
```